# How to transform the right side of SVG blocks a bit to the back?

Tags: svg, tiles

How do i transform/rotate(?) the right side of these SVG blocks to appear more the back?

The right side of the tiles should not be higher but more to the back giving it more dept.

[image]

This is my SVG.

````
width="1250.345px" height="350.345px" viewBox="-30 -30 1250.345 350.345" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1250.574 350.574;"
xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M 14,19 L14,100 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
 <path d="M 117,20 L117,100 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
 <path d="M 220,20 L220,100 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
</g>
<g>
 <path d="M 14,103 L14,183 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
 <path d="M 117,103 L117,183 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
 <path d="M 220,103 L220,183 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
</g>
<g>
 <path d="M 14,187 L14,267 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
 <path d="M 117,187 L 117,267 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
 <path d="M 220,187 L 220,267 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
</g>
</svg> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by

> The right side of the tiles should not be higher but more to the back giving it more dept.

when that appears to be exactly what you have drawn.

You can reproduce your drawing using a `skewY()` transform.

```html
 <svg version="1.1" id="scgblocks" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="1250.345px" height="350.345px" viewBox="-30 -30 1250.345 350.345">
  <g transform="skewY(-9)">
    <g>
      <path d="M 14,19 L14,100 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
      <path d="M 117,20 L117,100 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
      <path d="M 220,20 L220,100 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M 14,103 L14,183 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
      <path d="M 117,103 L117,183 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
      <path d="M 220,103 L220,183 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M 14,187 L14,267 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
      <path d="M 117,187 L 117,267 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
      <path d="M 220,187 L 220,267 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Is that what you wanted?

However, if instead you mean that you want it to have perspective, then you need to do it a slightly different way.  You can't use perspective transforms (yet) inside an SVG, but perspective transforms *are* allowed on HTML elements.  So, as long as the SVG is in an web page, then you can apply a perspective transform to the entire `<svg>` element because browsers treat top level `<svg>` elements like other HTML elements.

```css
svg {
  transform: perspective(1800px) rotateY(50deg);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="scgblocks" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="1250.345px" height="350.345px" viewBox="-30 -30 1250.345 350.345">
  <g>
    <path d="M 14,19 L14,100 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
    <path d="M 117,20 L117,100 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
    <path d="M 220,20 L220,100 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
  </g>
  <g>
    <path d="M 14,103 L14,183 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
    <path d="M 117,103 L117,183 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
    <path d="M 220,103 L220,183 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
  </g>
  <g>
    <path d="M 14,187 L14,267 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
    <path d="M 117,187 L 117,267 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
    <path d="M 220,187 L 220,267 l 100,0 l 0,-80 Z" style="fill:#B1BCB6;" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the decision, I will add only one clarification.
Firefox 72.0.1 already supports perspective and rotation transformation.  An example of transforming each row of rectangles SVG  https://jsfiddle.net/tn76Lgbv/

Comment: @Alexandr_TT As you say, you can't use them cross-browser. That's why I decided to keep my answer simple and said that you can't use them "yet".

Comment: In fairness - I did not say anything about cross-browser compatibility. I just clarified that Firefox it supports the transformation of perspectives inside svg.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Sorry, my comment ended up a bit malformed. I intended it to read "As you say, it works in Firefox, but you can't use them cross-browser..."

Comment: I always appreciate your answers positively, they are very useful for me, I use a lot of your interesting ideas in my work, and I rated this answer as useful